# prove distance preserving maps also preserve Jordan measure.

Tags: measure-theory

I have just begun measure theory and have a question about  measures which  have not been addressed in the books I have access to:
let $f$ be a one to one map from set $S$ to $T$(in $\mathbb R^n$ for any dimension $n$)such that it preserves distance. Prove that the Jordan measure of $T$ is the same as the Jordan measure of $S$.

Comment: First prove that $f$ is affine-linear, then prove it has determinant $\pm 1$. Edit: this doesn't quite work for arbitrary $S$, sorry.

Comment: will this work for rotated or translated elementary sets?

Comment: and do you also have any idea as to why, despite being an obvious question this has not been addressed in many measure theory books?

Comment: Incidentally, most measure theory books will cover Lebesgue measure, not Jordan one, since Lebesgue is better behaved. Is there a reason you are learning Jordan measure and not Lebesgue?

Comment: @diracdeltafunk: This will work when S is a rectangle and that’s  the key to the proof.

Comment: @Moishe kohan Jordan measure was before lebesgue in my book as an intro..I haven't read the part about lebesgue yet and was just curious about this question

Comment: could you explain how guaranteeing the map is affine linear will guarantee the answer?

Comment: This would be a corollary of the change of variable formula in integrals, which is usually proven during development of Lebesgue integral. The fact nobody bothers with proving it separately for Jordan measure is to avoid repeating proofs.